# Simple Bar Plot with dimple.js and d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a very basic bar plot with dimple.js. When I render in the browser, it shows only the axes and axis labels, but no bars. Any help appreciated. I am using python to create a localhost.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2> Rise of the Machines: R&D on Unmanned Aerial Aircrafts</h2>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
function draw(data) {

      /*
        D3.js setup code
      */
    var margin = 75;
    var width = 1400 - margin;
    var height = 600 - margin;

      /* Find body tag, append svg, and add chart group tag*/
    var svg = d3.select("body") 
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin)
        .attr("height", height + margin)
      .append("g")
        .attr("class","chart");

      /*
        Dimple.js Chart construction code
      */

      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data); 
      x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "");
      y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Share of Global Spending (%)");
      myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
      myChart.draw();
    };

d3.csv("data.csv", draw);
```

Comment: Could you post cvs header and a few rows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

You'd not tell to dimple where to get the data:

```
  x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "");     //<---- X values
  y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Share of Global Spending (%)"); // <--- Y values
```

example

```
var data = [
  { "Word":"Hello", "Awesomeness":2000 },
  { "Word":"World", "Awesomeness":3000 }
];

chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Word");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
```

another example

```
var data = [
  { "data1":"Hello", "data2":2000 },
  { "data1":"World", "data2":3000 }
];

chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "data1");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "data2");
```

You must point to data origin, from csv column name. With your csv:

```
Xdata, Yvalue
1,10
2,20
3,30
4,20
```

Your code:

```
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Xdata");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Yvalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

On the [dimple website](http://dimplejs.org/), it seems to be recommended procedure to use .tsv (tab seperated values) as opposed to comma seperated values.

Here is a sample (vertical) bar chart code taken from the [site](http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical)

```
<html>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <script src="/lib/d3.v3.4.8.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.tsv("/data/example_data.tsv", function (data) {
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 330)
      myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", ["Price Tier", "Channel"]);
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Unit Sales");
      myChart.addSeries("Channel", dimple.plot.bar);
      myChart.addLegend(65, 10, 510, 20, "right");
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>
</html>
```

Hopefully, this will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: there is a d3 (only - no dimple) csv bar chart link on github, but again when you follow the link that they refer to (as 'derived from'), the original used .tsv. link is https://gist.github.com/d3noob/8952219  You may find this other link http://blog.decayingcode.com/post/easy-charting-in-javascript-with-d3js-and-dimple-from-csv-data/ helpful